# openssl include path not recognised by Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssl, pjsip

Am trying to build PJSIP project with SSL using VS12.

i have installed OPENSSL project in my PC  at C:\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32 . and added include dir in my project and give path in properties files too but getting below error

12. IntelliSense: cannot open source file "openssl/ssl.h" c:\Users\Kumar\Desktop\PJ-Project 1.0\1.0\pjsip\src\pjsip\sip_transport_tls_ossl.c 45 1 pjsip_core
13. IntelliSense: cannot open source file "openssl/err.h" c:\Users\Kumar\Desktop\PJ-Project 1.0\1.0\pjsip\src\pjsip\sip_transport_tls_ossl.c 46 1 pjsip_core
14. IntelliSense: cannot open source file "openssl/bio.h" c:\Users\Kumar\Desktop\PJ-Project 1.0\1.0\pjsip\src\pjsip\sip_transport_tls_ossl.c 44 1 pjsip_core

any insight over above error ?

FYI:

i have include the include the header path in following places....

> 1) project properties ----->General ------>AdditionalInclude Properties 
>   ----->C:\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\include;
>
> 2)Project properties ---- >Linker ------ >General
>   ----->AdditionalLibarariesdIRECTORIES---C:\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\lib
>
> 3)lINKER -----Input -----AdditionalDependies--- >libeay32.lib
>   ssleay32.lib

anything else i have missed ? please share ur thoughts

Comment: This seems to be a problem with including the header files, rather than lib linking. Could you show us the part of the C file with the `#include`s?

Answer (score 0):

For the steps 1 and 2 use the entire path to inc32 folder. 
In my case it is C:\openssl-1.0.2g\inc32.

For the third step use the value libeay32.lib